# issue with bootstrap nav bar collapse icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a bootstrap website and trying to make the nav bar collapsable work. The nav toggle button shows up regardless. How can I restrict it to show up when the nav bar goes to a medium?

the code is :

```
enter code here
```

```html
  </!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Website</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
         </script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
  <!--mobile first -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
     <body>

         <div style="background-color: black;">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
   <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="background-color: black"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsenavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">The New Laws</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Get Qualified</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">What Is Record Suspension</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Why Do I Need A Waiver</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
        </nav>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is referencing Bootstrap 3, so the Bootstrap 4 Navbar isn't going to work

Answer (score 0):

You use nav's code of bootstrap 4 and add links and scripts of bootstrap 3....
**1. you can add links/script of bootstrap 4 and then it works:**
 **This is the scripts/links:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div style="background-color: black;">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
   <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="background-color: black"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsenavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">The New Laws</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Get Qualified</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">What Is Record Suspension</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Why Do I Need A Waiver</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
```

**2. you can use bootstrap 3:https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp**